# Jboss 7.1.1 - HornetQ reconnect errors

Tags: jboss7.x, hornetq

Jboss 7.1.1 server is throwing hornetq reconnect errors on one of the queue I configured. I have removed messages from the queue using CLI and deleted the data folder as well, but this error is not going away. Appreciate any help.

CLI command

```
 [standalone@localhost:9999 /] /subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/jms-queue=myQueueC:remove-messages
  {
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => 0
  }
```

Exception stack trace from the server log

```
10:53:47,505 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivation] (default-short-running-threads-threads - 1) Attempting to reconnect        org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivationSpec(ra=org.hornetq.ra.HornetQResourceAdapter@20ebddc6  destination=java:/queue/C destinationType=javax.jms.Queue ack=Auto-acknowledge durable=false   clientID=null user=null maxSession=15)
10:53:47,518 ERROR [org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivation] (default-short-running-threads-threads - 1) Unable to reconnect org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivationSpec(ra=org.hornetq.ra.HornetQResourceAdapter@20ebddc6 destination=java:/queue/C destinationType=javax.jms.Queue ack=Auto-acknowledge durable=false clientID=null user=null maxSession=15): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface javax.resource.spi.endpoint.MessageEndpoint is not visible from class loader
       at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:616) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Proxy.java:592) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache$Factory.get(WeakCache.java:244) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache.get(WeakCache.java:141) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:455) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:738) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.JBossMessageEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(JBossMessageEndpointFactory.java:56)
       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.inflow.JBossMessageEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(JBossMessageEndpointFactory.java:49)
       at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQMessageHandler.setup(HornetQMessageHandler.java:185) [hornetq-ra-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
       at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivation.setup(HornetQActivation.java:296) [hornetq-ra-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
       at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivation.handleFailure(HornetQActivation.java:566) [hornetq-ra-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
       at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivation$SetupActivation.run(HornetQActivation.java:609) [hornetq-ra-2.2.13.Final.jar:]
       at org.jboss.jca.core.workmanager.WorkWrapper.run(WorkWrapper.java:212)
       at org.jboss.threads.SimpleDirectExecutor.execute(SimpleDirectExecutor.java:33)
       at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.runTask(QueueExecutor.java:801)
       at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.access$100(QueueExecutor.java:45)
       at org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker.run(QueueExecutor.java:821)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom JBoss module, make sure that your module has dependency to **javax.resource.api**.

```
<module>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.resource.api" />
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Another solution is: Add **Dependencies: javax.resource.api** line to your **MyApp.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF** file.